# How can I compare the different types of cards with enums?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I've got the following script

```
public enum ColourType
{
    CLOVERS,
    DIAMONDS,
    HEARTS,
    PIKES,
    COUNT
};

[System.Serializable]
public struct ColourSprite
{ 
    public ColourType colour;
    public Sprite sprite;
};

public ColourSprite[] colourSprites;
```

https://pastebin.com/zyZEYqzL

Is there a way I can compare the colour types on click, and if they match lets say execute some piece of code (destroy them etc)

Tried by comparing the sprites but still couldn't make it work

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a `isSelected` property, that you set to true for the card on which you click first. When you click on a card, the program checks if some other card is already selected. If yes, it juste checks if their colour are equal (with `==`) and then destroy them or whatever. If no, this is the first card selected, so you set the boolean `isSelected` to `true`.